# Call requires API level 14 (current min is 10):

Tags: android

How can I solve this error ? I do not understand the reason behind this error ?

code

```
devicePolicyManager.setCameraDisabled(demoDeviceAdmin, false);
```

error :

> Call requires API level 14 (current min is 10):
>   android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager#setCameraDisabled   DevicePolicyDemoActivity.java   /DevicePolicyDemoActivity/src/com/marakana/android/devicepolicydemo line
>   62    Android Lint Problem

Answer (score 10):

It is actually a warning from Lint, rather than an error. If you want to keep your current minimum SDK level, you can suppress the warning, and check the SDK level yourself, at run time.

Comment: +1 for a useful suggestion, I suspect the asker doesn't want to exclude Android 2.x and 3.x from the app un-necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your minimum SDK level, defined in the manifest, is 10. `devicePolicyManager. setCameraDisabled(demoDeviceAdmin, false);` requires API 14+.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Because `devicePolicyManager.setCameraDisabled(demoDeviceAdmin, false);`requires API 14+.

**Note:** (by  Joachim Isaksson)

> though that this will raise the "bar" for running the app from Android 2.3.3 to Android 4.0.

Comment: Note though that this will raise the "bar" for running the app from Android 2.3.3 to Android 4.0.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes, but this is decided by the questioner

Comment: Yep, no downvote, just thought the questioner should know what the fixed meant to him.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yep, and I add your suggestion into my post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your target version above API level 14. Right click your project.
Select properties. Go to Android. Select version above API level 14.

Answer (score 0):

`setCameraDisabled()` method is introduced in `API level 14`. Have a look at official documentation for it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setCameraDisabled%28android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean%29). You should change the API level of your application, if you want to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Make this change in your manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```