# Android Call requires API level 13 (current min is 10): android.view.Display#getSize

Tags: android

I'm trying to target as many architectures as possible, as well as having few warnings as possible.

```
Point dims = new Point();
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
      mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(dims);
} else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13) {
  dims.x = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
  dims.y = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
}
```

But this gives me the error and warning:

```
Call requires API level 13 (current min is 10): android.view.Display#getSize
The method getWidth() from the type Display is deprecated
```

[They say to change the manifesto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14357344/1287856) (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11789275/1287856)) but why is this above not working for the compiler? Can't I get rid of both with the range of apis 10 to 18 ?

Comment: does it crash your app when you use it? Usually it gives you an error but the program will still run. It's mostly just a warning

Comment: Ignoring this kind of warnings will make that devices running a lower `API` than requested will fail and probably your app will throw an `Exception`. Usually there are workarounds to not need to increment the `minSdk`, I don't know how this one might be avoided, though.

Comment: OR what you can try and do is `DisplayMetrics display = new DisplayMetrics();` then do `getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(display);` This will allow you to then get the width and height via `int width = display.widthPixels;` or `heightPixels` for height

Comment: It does not compile because of the first one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have the SDK version checking in place so the deprecation warning from compiler and lint warning about new API can be ignored.

Pull the code snippet to a separate method and add the following annotations to it:

```
@TargetApi(13)
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

Note that the `if` part of your `else if` is redundant. Plain `else` is enough.

Comment: That was it. I put the two at the same time and voilà the warning and the error are removed.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the display size, the recommended way is to use

```
context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
```

instead. Then use the [widthPixels](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#widthPixels) and [heightPixels](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#heightPixels) properties.

Using the current context gives you the dimensions of the current display in case of multiple displays, which is also safer.